# Archer Questionnaires, tally the total questions that has answered

Tags: archer

I'm new in archer, i need help on the calculating questions.

We need to tally question that has been answer.
***sample:*** have 5 question but 3 of it has been answer 
***to display***: **3 of 5 Question**

```
<br><br>
GEN* - question field
<br>
total answer - field i need to add to the layout
<br>
<br>
**code:**<br>
IF(AND(NOT(ISEMPTY([GEN-01: Management Commitment (*HC*)]))),
<br>(NOT(ISEMPTY([GEN-02: ITC Department Staffing (*HC*)]))),
<br>(NOT(ISEMPTY([GEN-03: ITC Communication (e.g., Process Changes, Regulatory Changes)]))),
<br>(NOT(ISEMPTY([GEN-04: Internal Escalation]))) 
<br>VALUEOF([Total Answer]), “Completed”, 
VALUEOF([Total Answer]), “Not Completed”)
<br><br>
```

my script is not working

Comment: Is this your CUSTOM object or your calculated field? How is it that HTML tags are present in the calculation?

Comment: the HTML is cause when you create a question but apparently it will not convert it.

Calculated field, anyway i already solve the issue